Replacing my tankless water heater with a HE one
So I am planning on replacing my standard efficiency tankless with a HE one. I have a SS vent pipe that is a straight shot to the roof. My house is on a slab and is one level. I would like to use the SS vent as a chase for my new 2in pipe to run in the SS vent and out the roof. My question is how would I terminate this on the roof side so water will not fall down the chase ? Is there a coupler I can get to where it will let the 2in PCV go past the old SS tubing and stick out the vent ? Then the coupling base can cover the the old SS vent (see image for reference )
vent idea

Unusual mix of terminology - is this in US/Canada or someplace else? (Matters because codes and standard practices vary around the world). Model # of old heater? Model # of new heater?

There are rubber boots used to seal pipes to roofs.  Maybe clamping one to the PVC pipe will work, as a hat/cone.

I assume that this high efficiency tankless WH is a "condensing" model. This means that  you will have to conduct acidic condensate to a drain. Have you planned for this? Is your current non-condensing WH at the end of its service life? Or are you thinking about replacing it proactively before it fails?

Before you go any further, check the installation instructions for the maximum length of 2" pipe that the device will allow, and how much from that length to deduct for each 45 and 90 degree elbow. You want to make sure the length of your design does not exceed their maximum. You may be allowed extra length if you switch to a larger pipe.
